# How to build using SBT for ONE job only

Tags: scala, build, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

I am trying to build a single spark scala job.
So far as I know, it should be done using `<sbt assembly>` command in the spark directory, however using this method will build all jobs existing there.
Is there a way to build a single specific file at a time ?

Comment: How do you define a Job? Do you mean a Jar?

Comment: A job is .scala file that needs to be build using sbt

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to split your project into multiple SBT subprojects (it's possible that you already do that). Then you can use [SBT multi-project build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html).

If you do so, you can [navigate](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Multi-Project.html#Navigating+projects+interactively) to any subproject and build it separately. Note that you can build a separate JAR only if it's built per subproject, not in the aggregate root project. If you want to build non-interactively you can pass the same commands to SBT as you would type in SBT shell:

```
sbt "project client" "package"
```

Replace `package` command with any other packaging command you use like `assembly` or `one-jar`, etc.

For an example project check [this](https://github.com/izmailoff/remote-akka-server-template/blob/master/project/Build.scala). The project structure is as follows (SBT shell):

```
root > projects
[info]     client
[info]     common
[info]   * root
[info]     server
```

Projects are defined like this:

```
lazy val root = Project(id = "root",
                        base = file("."))
                        .aggregate(common, client, server)

lazy val client = Project(id = "client", base = file("client"))
                         settings(clientSettings: _*) dependsOn(common)

lazy val server = Project(id = "server", base = file("server"))
                         settings(serverSettings: _*) dependsOn(common)

lazy val common = Project(id = "common", base = file("common"))
                         settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

As you can see there is a `root` project that aggregates 3 other projects. To build `client` or `server` you have to build `common` first. However, `client` can be built separately from `server` and vice-versa. To build everything you just build `root`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I'll try it out